# Command `remote_directory` fails on persmissions

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-solo

I'm trying to copy a folder from my FTP server to my local PC with the following code:

```
src = "http://moo-repo.wdf.ETC.corp:8080/static/lit/ETC/MDMInternalTools/"

remote_directory "c:\\Users\\Desktop" do
  source src
  rights :full_control, 'everyone'
  action :create
end
```

Sometimes it fails with the error:

```
FileNotFound: cookbook litc-mdmfiles has no directory
files/default/http://moo
repo.wdf.ETC.corp:8080/static/lit/ETC/MDMInternalTools/
```

And sometimes I get this:

```
Chef::Exceptions::InsufficientPermissions: Cannot create 
remote_directory[C:\Users\public\Desktop
```

Can someone please advise?

Comment: Watch the quotes and backslashes in files pathes, especially when talking to windows.

Answer (score 1):

The `remote_directory` resource doesn't do what you think it does. It is for copying from the `files/` directory inside the cookbook, like `cookbook_file` does for single files. This is a common mistake, as `remote_file` does single-file downloads from HTTP (or similar) sources. There is no way to download a "directory" over HTTP as it doesn't support folder-like semantics in a generalized way. You mentioned you are transferring from an FTP server (though the example code uses HTTP), if so you could either find or make a resource which does this synchronization over FTP, but I don't know of one off hand.